# MIPS total number of instruction executed

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I have this code:

```
      addi $t1, $zero, $zero
LOOP: lw $s1,0($s0)
      add $s2, $s2, $s1
      addi $s0, $s0, 4
      addi $t1, $t1, 1
      slti $t2, $t1, 100
      bne $t2, $s0, LOOP
```

The question is what is the total number of instructions executed.

Assuming the s0=0

What I think is is the loop terminate when t2 == s0
t2 is one for any t1<100 and s0 increment by 4 in every cycle. So does that makes the loop infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I think is is the loop terminate when t2 == s0.

Correct.

> t2 is one for any t1<100.

Correct.

> s0 increment by 4 in every cycle.

Correct.

> So does that makes the loop infinite?

Not necessarily.

If `lw $s1,0($s0)` tries to access memory that is protected, your program will be terminated by the OS.

Also, if any of the adding instructions result in an overflow, your program will probably be terminated by the OS as well. Only unsigned add instructions (`addu` and the like) produce no exceptions/traps.

Comment: Good points, one more thing I am wondering about, if we are using 32 bit addressing then after 2^32 we ll run out of address, then does that reset to the base? assuming the assigned memory for the program is bigger than 2^32 (if it's even possible!!)

Comment: Your registers are 32-bit, aren't they? So, there's no chance to address more than 2^32 bytes of memory or even "assign".